# Bellwoods Brewery Beer in the UK

Tags: ipa, local, buying

So, I was in Toronto (Canada) a little while ago and absolutely fell in love with a couple of the beers from [Bellwoods Brewery](http://bellwoodsbrewery.com/). Specifically:

- Witchshark; and
- Monogamy

I have been casually looking online to see if I could find their beers here in the London (England) or on the internet, but with no luck.

Anyone know if I can find these beers somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it they sell their beers on rotation in their [own bottle shop](http://bellwoodsbrewery.com/faq/):

> We are just a humble micro brewery producing small batches of beer. Often times people develop a love affair with one particular beer (Roman Candle fanatics tend to be the most assertive!), but we brew over 50 styles in a year! With only 9 fermentors this ultimately means that availability works in ebbs and flows. If your favourite beer isn’t on draft or in the bottle shop, this gives you a chance to experiment with something new. We promise, there are no wrong choices.

They are available in some restaurants and bars in Toronto (they don't have a list of which ones those are on their website), however this doesn't help you in the UK.

They don't ship, and they don't seem to have any links to a proper distributor (from the sounds of it on their website, they sell everything they can make in house already). The relevant bit from their FAQ there:

> Do you ship to other parts of Canada? The US? Jupiter?
>
> At this point no. There’s no legal way to ship beer to an individual. Stay tuned for an online retail store where you’ll be able to purchase merchandise. Aliens, be damned!

Looks like your best bet is to head back to Toronto and hit their bottle shop. That's not too far of a drive from the UK...right?

Comment: Hopefully I can convince work that I _really_ need to go back to Toronto for. You know. Important work things... Ah well, that's sort of what I suspected. Thanks for looking into it!